# snmptrapd traphandle not able to run java command in tcl scriptg

Tags: java, tcl

I have this tcl file which will get run by snmptrapd traphandle . The thing is that after exec its not able to run.
Tcl code

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set traps [read stdin]

set trapout [open C:/Users/test-machine/Desktop/Database_traps_event_test.txt a+];

puts $trapout $traps

puts $trapout "before exec"

exec "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.5.0_22/bin/java" -cp C:/Users/test-machine/Desktop/  Hello $traps  >> C:/Users/test-machine/Desktop/result.txt


puts $trapout "after exec"
```

snptrapd.conf(which will redirect the trap to tcl file) file content

```
traphandle  IF-MIB::linkDown tclsh "C:\tclfile.tcl"
```

and the Database_traps_event_test.txt file output is

```
<UNKNOWN>
UDP: [192.168.1.19]:36769->[0.0.0.0]:0
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.system.sysUpTime.sysUpTimeInstance 2:4:32:00.38
.iso.org.dod.internet.snmpV2.snmpModules.snmpMIB.snmpMIBObjects.snmpTrap.snmpTrapOID.0 .iso.org.dod.internet.snmpV2.snmpModules.snmpMIB.snmpMIBObjects.snmpTraps.linkDown
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifIndex.1 8
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifAdminStatus.8 up
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifOperStatus.8 down

before exec
```

As it shown clearly that in

> Database_traps_event_test.txt

"after exec" is not getting printed.It means "exec" is not getting executed.Can someone please explain it to me.

Comment: It may mean that the exec is not finished yet. You might want to check the process explorer to see if that java process is still running.

Comment: Doesn't Java require the use of native filenames in its classpath?